# binary file invalid content reading

Tags: c, binary

I would like to write a program that opens a text file that contains numbers.
The program should create a new binary file in which the first number is the number of numbers in the whole line.

My problem is that when I want to check if the program has written the numbers well, the number of numbers is written well, but the rest is the same for each line

EXAMPLE:

> 1.2222 0.2222 1111 0.111112 111111 5 3 1 9
>
> 4 4.33333 3.222  31.222
>
> 83883838 73.383883 83.344449494
>
> 12.3333 44444 322 9999.99999 7

**this is what a file should look like**

> 9 1.2222 0.2222 1111 0.111112 111111 5 3 1 9
>
> 4 4 4.33333 3.222  31.222
>
> 3 83883838 73.383883 83.344449494
>
> 5 12.3333 44444 322 9999.99999 7

**and this is how it looks to me**

> 9 12.3333 44444 322 9999.99999 7
>
> 4 12.3333 44444 322 9999.99999 7
>
> 3 12.3333 44444 322 9999.99999 7
>
> 5 12.3333 44444 322 9999.99999 7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

struct rec
{
    size_t num;
    char *arr;
};

int number_of_numbers(char * buffer)
{
    int counter, state;
    int i;
   i=counter = state = OUT;
    
    while((buffer[i]!='\n')&&(buffer[i]!=EOF))
    {
        if(buffer[i]==' '||buffer[i]=='\t') state = OUT;
        else if(state==OUT)
        {
            state = IN;
            counter++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    return counter;
}


int how_many_lines(char *buffer)
{
    int i,counter;
    
    i=0;
    counter = 1;
    while(buffer[i]!=EOF)
    {
        if(buffer[i]=='\n') counter++;
        i++;
    }
    
    return counter;
}


int main()
{
    FILE *f,*f_2;
   
    long lSize;
    char *buffer;
    struct rec r;

    int i;
   
    
   
    f = fopen("f", "r");
    f_2=fopen("nf", "wb");
    if(!f) return 1;
    
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(f);
    rewind (f);
    
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
    r.arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
   
    while(fgets(buffer,lSize,f)!=NULL)
   {
       r.num = number_of_numbers(buffer);
       r.arr = buffer;
       fwrite(&r, sizeof(struct rec), 1, f_2);
   }
    fclose(f_2);
   
    f_2=fopen("nf", "rb");
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
       {
         fread(&r,sizeof(struct rec),1,f_2);
           printf("%d %s \n",r.num, r.arr);
      
       }
 
    fclose(f);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(f_2);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if the problem lies in the record, if you read it or maybe somewhere else

Comment: Pointers are local to the currently running process, you can't save pointers to a file and then reload in another process (even if it's the same program).

Comment: As for the problem you have and ask about: You write the same pointer for all elements in the file. All `r.arr` will point to the single array `buffer`. Which after the loop will contain the contents of the last line you read from the input. It's this pointer you then print.

Comment: So how i can fix it? Will it be correctly stored in the file?

Comment: The file stores the *pointer* `arr`, not the full contents of `buffer`. For that you need `arr` to be an actual array.

Comment: I have to create an array in structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct rec
{
    size_t num;
    char *arr;
};
```

While writing a `size_t` to a file may make some sense, writing a `char *` to a file doesn't really make any sense. Remember, a `char *` is a fixed-length pointer that holds the address at which something is stored. What the point of writing the address at which something is stored into a file?

```
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
```

Okay, so `buffer` always contains the address of this one block of memory that you allocated.

```
   r.arr = buffer;
```

So the value of `r.arr` is always the address of that one single block of memory. What's the point of writing the address of a block of memory to a file? And what's the point of writing the address of the very same block of memory to a file over and over? Maybe you want to try writing the *contents* of that buffer to the file instead?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to save the content to a file, not the address

Comment: How I can fix it?

Comment: @Daim123 My recommendation would be to not try to write code like this at all and use proper serialization. If you want to write data to a file, which is a stream of bytes, define a file format in terms of bytes and then put the data in the right places. Punching "c serialization" into your favorite search engine should get you started.